# Image not refreshed after taking a photo from a camera

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2

I am using this simple code with ionic 2 :

```
<button (click)="takePicture()" >Take a pic!</button>
<img [src]="url || '//:0'">
```

Then this is my Typescript page :

```
import {Page} from "ionic-framework/ionic";

@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/smartscan/smartScan.html'
}
)

export class SmartScan {

public url:string;

constructor() {
    console.log("Starting SmartScan page ...");
}

public takePicture() {
    console.log("Going to take a pic ...");
    navigator.camera.getPicture( (imageURI) => {

        this.url = imageURI;

        console.log("URI of the picture taken is : "+this.url);

        console.log(JSON.stringify(this));

        //var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        //image.src = imageURI;

    }, function (err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }, {});

   /* this.url = "http://maison-cresci.fr/uploads/images/nice_cresci_slide_environnement_003.jpg";
*/
}

}
```

After taking the picture, nothing is displayed. I noticed that the "src" is not updated by Angular. I tested a part of the code in comments thats works using "var image= ... image.src=..." but is directly manipulating the DOM and I don't want this.

Please can you see where the problem is ?

Comment: Got exactly the same problem.Please refer to my question in ionic forum: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/the-change-of-data-in-controller-doesnt-update-automatically/42263. Have you fixed the issue already?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [zone.run()](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/NgZone-class.html#!#run) to reenter Angular zone from a task that was executed outside of the Angular zone.

That worked for me for async tasks with local storage.

Something like:

```
public takePicture() {
    console.log("Going to take a pic ...");
    navigator.camera.getPicture((imageURI) => {

         console.log("URI of the picture taken is : "+imageURI);
         zone.run(()=>{ this.url = imageURI; })

        //var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        //image.src = imageURI;

     }, (err) => {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }, {});
}
```

Comment: i tried without success :/  the view is still not refreshed

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different approach to the callback function, named the [arrow function notation](http://www.codebelt.com/typescript/arrow-function-typescript-tutorial/):

```
public takePicture() {
    console.log("Going to take a pic ...");
    navigator.camera.getPicture((imageURI) => {
         this.url = imageURI;

         console.log("URI of the picture taken is : "+this.url);

        //var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
        //image.src = imageURI;

     }, (err) => {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
    }, {});
}
```

Notice how I have replaced the `function() {}` with `() => {}`, this way the `this` in `this.url` actually refers to the component object

Comment: The whole confusion was about using the wrong zone. You need to one get passed to the constructor (`NgZone`) instead the global `zone`.

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it worked , here is the full code solution :

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6340#issuecomment-179712658

It needs to use zone.run() around the property to be modified and inject zone variable into the constructor

> the constructor of your component should look like

```ts
export class PicutrePage {
  constructor(app: IonicApp, nav: NavController, params: NavParams, NgZone zone) {
    this.nav = nav;
    this.thumbnail = 'img/placeholder.png';    
    this.zone = zone;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem by adding '?' + a random number after the picture URI (e.g. myImage.jpg?74374565346). Doing this the hybrid app container (the browser) is forced to refresh when the picture is refreshed.

This solution works in the case you are changing a picture in your local file system but you are using the same URI or filename.