# Angular two way binding of image not working as expected

Tags: angular

I have an angular component that displays a base64 image string got from websocket on the html using the image tag. I poll the websocket every second and try to display it on the page. Here is my code:

html of component:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class= "video">
        <img [src]="_DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(getBase64Image())" style="margin-left:30%;width:800px;height:400px;">
    </div>
</div>
```

the typescript code:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

export class HelloComponent implements OnInit{
  messageText: string;
  messages: Array<any>;
  socket: any;
  subscription: Subscription;
  intervalId: any;
  image: any;

  constructor(public _DomSanitizationService: DomSanitizer ) {
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getLatestFrame();
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.getLatestFrame, 1000);
  }

  getLatestFrame(){
    this.socket = io(environment.websocket_url);
    this.socket.emit('hello', {
      msg: 'Client to server, can you hear me server?'
    });

    this.socket.on('frame', (data: any) => {
      this.image = data;
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.intervalId);
  }

  getBase64Image(): string {
    return "data:image/png;base64, " + this.image;
  }
}
```

With this code, I can see the `getLatestFrame()` is being called every 1 second like I intended it to. The `getBase64Image()` is also being called and I can see the new base64 string on every second meaning the image has changed but however on the UI, I can see the first frame only that got loaded during the ngInit only and no change after that. Can't understand why.

Comment: Does it help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34660141/image-not-refreshed-after-taking-a-photo-from-a-camera

Comment: Tried but it aint helping me, no error but the image doesn't refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-render the component on any input change by calling the `ngOnInit()` method as it re-renders the component without reloading the page.

```
getLatestFrame(){
    var _this = this;
    this.socket = io(environment.websocket_url);
    this.socket.emit('hello', {
        msg: 'Client to server, can you hear me server?'
    });

    this.socket.on('frame', (data: any) => {
        this.image = data;
        _this.ngOnInit();
    });
}
```